# Service that allows customised content newsletters

Tags: ruby, email, sendmail, mailchimp, campaign-monitor

I am currently looking at building a web app that allows a user to sign in and receive a list of their tweets from the previous week in an email this information will be stored and pulled in from a db

Now at first I thought I could use something like postmark but this is apparently only for transactional emails and not bulk newsletters. I guess mine would be a newsletter as it would send to lots of people at the same time every week. But my question is how could I use a service like mailchimp that would allow completely customised content for each recipent? Is this possible with a service like mailchimp or campaign monitor?

Answer (score 0):

If you want customized content per subscriber in the one email campaign (dynamic content), MailChimp is the way to go. Campaign Monitor has yet to implement that functionality.

Another option if you're a developer is to use [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/).

Comment: Thanks John, do you have a link to some documentation I couldn't find anything on the site.

Comment: Here: http://mailchimp.com/features/dynamic-content/ , the customisation seems to be minimal but it is there.

Comment: Those are both really useful, but neither seems to be that flexible or powerful. I would need some way of being able to essentially create repeater fields for each tweet.

Comment: If you use your tweets a rss there are a few different tools that have repeaters. I know Campaign Monitor has a cool tool for that

Comment: [Campaign Monitor 1-click rss content](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3663/) and here is [MailChimp's Twitter Integration](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-do-i-integrate-twitter-with-mailchimp)